# DataTemplate localization using WPFLocalizationExtension

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, localization

I'm using [WPFLocalizationExtension](https://wpflocalizeextension.codeplex.com/) to localize a C#/ .Net4.5 application but I didn't manage to localize DropDown Menus with custom `DataTemplate` because I can't use the `DisplayMemberPath`. For ordinary dropdown localization works like this:

```
<telerik:RadComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding GlassColors}" 
                     SelectedValue="{Binding Ampule.ID_GlassColor, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                     SelectedValuePath="ID_GlassColor" 
                     DisplayMemberPath="{lang:Loc dmp_GlassColor}"/>
```

The `ComboBox` example above is linked to a database table containing to language. The displayed language is changed by the localized `DisplayMemberPath`. This approach is very easy and I can recommend it to everyone else. How ever it doesn't work for comboboxes using a custom `DataTemplate`. See example below:

```
<telerik:RadComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding PackagingTypesFilter}" 
                     SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedPackagingTypeFilter}"          
                     SelectedValuePath="ID_PackagingType">
    <telerik:RadComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:Tbl_PackagingMaster_ID_PackagingType}">
            <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="24" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Image Source="{Binding TypeIcon, Converter={StaticResource StringToUriConverter}}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="0" Height="14" Margin="2" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding PackagingTypeDescription}" Style="{StaticResource TextBlockMediumSmallBlackStyle}" Grid.Column="1"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </telerik:RadComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</telerik:RadComboBox>
```

The `ItemSource` is a `Collection` where `PackagingTypeDescription` contains the English and `PackagingTypeDescriptionGerman` contains the German description.

**How can I localize the code sample above?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this using a `TemplateSelector`.

Here is the `TemplateSelector` class:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace Common.TemplateSelector
{
    public class LanguageTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
    {
        public DataTemplate TemplateEnglish { get; set; }
        public DataTemplate TemplateGerman { get; set; }

        public const string LanguageIdentifier = "de";

        public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
        {
            return Configuration.Configuration.Language == LanguageIdentifier ? this.TemplateGerman : this.TemplateEnglish;
        }
    }
}
```

And here the template definition and the definition of the `TemplateSelector` defined in the `<UserControl.Resources></UserControl.Resources>` area:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:Tbl_PackagingMaster_ID_PackagingType}" x:Key="PackagingTypeEnglish">
    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="24" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Image Source="{Binding TypeIcon, Converter={StaticResource StringToUriConverter}}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="0" Height="14" Margin="2" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding PackagingTypeDescription}" Style="{StaticResource TextBlockMediumSmallBlackStyle}" Grid.Column="1"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:Tbl_PackagingMaster_ID_PackagingType}" x:Key="PackagingTypeGerman">
    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="24" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Image Source="{Binding TypeIcon, Converter={StaticResource StringToUriConverter}}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="0" Height="14" Margin="2" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding PackagingTypeDescriptionGerman}" Style="{StaticResource TextBlockMediumSmallBlackStyle}" Grid.Column="1"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>

<templateSelector:LanguageTemplateSelector x:Key="PackagingTypeLanguageSelector"
                                           TemplateEnglish="{StaticResource PackagingTypeEnglish}" 
                                           TemplateGerman="{StaticResource PackagingTypeGerman}" />
```

This is how I use it for the `ComboBox`:

```
<telerik:RadComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding PackagingTypesFilter}"
                     SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedPackagingTypeFilter}"      
                     SelectedValuePath="ID_PackagingType"
                     ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource PackagingTypeLanguageSelector}" />
```

However, I'm still looking for a more elegant way to solve this.